# How to set up mongoDB bindIp?

Tags: mongodb

Something wrong happens when I'm trying to setup mongod.conf for connection from remote server.

When I paste my server ip address Mongo doesn't allow connection from it.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 111.111.11.111  #my server ip
```

When I allow connection from any server, mongo allows to connect from my server.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

I want to have an access to Mongo from localhost and from my server. I'm trying to paste these ip's both but Mongo allow connection from localhost only.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 111.111.11.111
```

What's wrong and how to use bindIp ?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation the value is a `string`, i.e. a single value.

Try following:

Use only `111.111.11.111`, localhost may work by default anyway.

Try these ones:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 
    - 127.0.0.1 
    - 111.111.11.111

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,111.111.11.111

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,111.111.11.111]
```

Otherwise use a firewall, either an external one or the internal firewall of your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I thought there has to be the IP address of the remote server. It's not right. There can be ip addresses of the network interfaces of the current machine.

Looking for here:

```
ifconfig -a | grep "inet"
```